# how many youtube videos can be embed in my website

Tags: iframe, youtube, html5-video, embed

How many YouTube videos can be embedded in my website? I embed videos 3 and unfortunately, is not one video shows a first video is included page and the rest did not show

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="420" height="315"  style="position:relative;z-index:1 !important;" 
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YlDAzMpbZso"
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="420" height="315"  style="position:relative;z-index:1 !important;" 
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YlDAzMpbZso"
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="420" height="315"  style="position:relative;z-index:1 !important;" 
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YlDAzMpbZso"
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: I edited his Question, hey wrote the code, but he didn't marked it as code. So it wasn't shown to us.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple elements with the same `id`. That's invalid HMTL.